# Adding inside a while loop php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a script that pulls values from a MySQL database and puts into into a variable. Each time it iterates, it pulls a new value. I want to add these values together. Here's what I have:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$getvalue = mysql_query("SELECT value FROM pointvalues WHERE code = '$row[code]'")or die(mysql_error()); 
$rowcode1 = mysql_fetch_array($getvalue);
$finalValue = $rowcode1["value"];
}
```

I want to keep adding $finalValue to itself.

Comment: There is a += operator for that.  But it's quicker to ask your RDBMS to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend  saving yourself all that work and simply changing your query to:

```
SELECT SUM(value) FROM pointvalues WHERE code = x
```

Reference: [`SUM`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum)

Comment: When I do this, I get "Resource id #7Resource id #8." Any idea?